# Redirect to the right language (i18n)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

## The goal

When a user accesses the application, regardless of controller, I want to redirect him to his (right) language based on specific criteria (see next).

## The problem

I already tried too much routes combination, but no success. See an example:

```
get '/', to: redirect('/:locale/home')
```

The result? The user is redirected to `/:locale/home`, in other words, there's not a language there, just raw `:locale`.

## Scenario

When user access `http://myapp.com/` I really want to redirect him to `http://myapp.com/en-US/` for example.

### Criteria

This is my `ApplicationController`:

```
[...]
def set_locale
   extracted_locale = params[:locale] || extract_locale_from_accept_language_headerw
   I18n.locale = (I18n::available_locales.include? extracted_locale.to_sym) ?
   extracted_locale : I18n.default_locale
end

Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:locale]= I18n.locale

private
   def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}/).first
   end
end
```

### TL;DR

The criteria is: if the user doesn't pass any language by URL, no problem! We get his `http_accept_language` and voi là! By the way, it's useless `http_accept_language` by now because always will have a parameter explaining to application what language the user is searching for, but I I just put for security reasons.

## Real question

Someone can explain me how to design a good route that performs what I want? I mean:

- `http://myapp.com/` => `http://myapp.com/en-US`
- `http://myapp.com/about-us` => `http://myapp.com/pt-BR/about-us`

## Doubts?

Am I missing something? Expressed myself bad? Please, feel free to report.

Comment: Living and learning, Mori. I'm not native. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Rails Internationalization (I18n)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) section *Setting the Locale from the URL Params*

In short, your routes should be something like this:

```
get '/:locale' => 'home#index'
get '/:locale/about-us' => 'home#about_us'    
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|nl/ do
   resources :books
end
```

And set default locate in your application_controller.rb

```
def default_url_options(options={})    
    { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

Comment: Hey, Anh! I already read the docs and nothing useful until now. I don't want to type `/pt-BR/` to be redirected - I want to let Rails resolve this for client.

Comment: You do mean this do you. Your homepage use default en-US and about-us use pt-BR
`http://myapp.com/` => `http://myapp.com/en-US`

`http://myapp.com/about-us` => `http://myapp.com/pt-BR/about-us`